# Notice: Undefined variable: csvFile inon line 160 ,Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given on line 160

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv, fgetcsv

> I'm trying to upload a csv file into a php web page that will
>   allow me to insert/update the data into an sql database. But after I selected my csv file and clicked import it shows the error above, still a noob at PHP
>   advanced thanks for any help and suggestions!

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['importSubmit'])){
       $csvMimes = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain');
       if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'],$csvMimes)){
           if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
               $csvFile = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
               fgetcsv($csvFile);
               while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE){
               require_once('../../mysqlConnector/mysql_connect.php');
               $query="UPDATE communitysurvey SET  stationID = '".$line[0]."',userID= '{$_SESSION['username']}', question1 = '".$line[1]."', question2 = '".$line[2]."', question3 = '".$line[3]."', question4 = '".$line[4]."', question5 = '".$line[5]."', question6 = '".$line[6]."', question7 = '".$line[7]."', question8 = '".$line[8]."', question9 = '".$line[9]."',question10 = '".$line[10]."', question11 = '".$line[11]."', question12 = '".$line[12]."', question13 = '".$line[13]."', question14 = '".$line[14]."',question15 = '".$line[15]."', question16 = '".$line[16]."', question17 = '".$line[17]."', question18 = '".$line[18]."', question19 = '".$line[19]."',question20 = '".$line[20]."', question21 = '".$line[21]."',question22 = '".$line[22]."', comments1 = '".$line[23]."', comments2 = '".$line[24]."'";   
               $result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
               }
        }
    }  
   fclose($csvFile);
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `fclose($csvFile);` in `if` condition that exist `$csvFile` variable:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['importSubmit'])){

    $csvMimes = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain');
    if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'],$csvMimes)){
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){

            $csvFile = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');

            fgetcsv($csvFile);

            while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE){

                require_once('../../mysqlConnector/mysql_connect.php');
                $query="UPDATE communitysurvey SET  stationID = '".$line[0]."',userID= '{$_SESSION['username']}', question1 = '".$line[1]."', question2 = '".$line[2]."', question3 = '".$line[3]."', question4 = '".$line[4]."', question5 = '".$line[5]."', question6 = '".$line[6]."', question7 = '".$line[7]."', question8 = '".$line[8]."', question9 = '".$line[9]."',question10 = '".$line[10]."', question11 = '".$line[11]."', question12 = '".$line[12]."', question13 = '".$line[13]."', question14 = '".$line[14]."',question15 = '".$line[15]."', question16 = '".$line[16]."', question17 = '".$line[17]."', question18 = '".$line[18]."', question19 = '".$line[19]."',question20 = '".$line[20]."', question21 = '".$line[21]."',question22 = '".$line[22]."', comments1 = '".$line[23]."', comments2 = '".$line[24]."'";

                $result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
            }

            fclose($csvFile);

        }
    }

}
?>
```